# List Button pass multiple IDs to apex page

Tags: apex, javascript, list, list-view, list-button

I have below javascript code on List Button that should pass multiple IDs to the mentioned VF Page. But this gives out an error encountered for Unexpected string.

List Button Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

alert('{!$Profile.Name}'); 

if( '{!$Profile.Name}' == 'System Administrator' || '{!$Profile.Name}' == 'CAM Administrator' ) 
{ 
    var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c )}; 
    var SelectedIds = ''; 
    var first = true; 

    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
        if(first) { 
            SelectedIds+="'"+records[i]+"'"; 
            first = false; 
        } else 
            SelectedIds+=",'"+records[i]+"'"; 
        } 

        var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id from Compliance_Incident_abv__c where Id in ("+SelectedIds+")"); 
}  else { 
    alert('Please select records to proceed.'); 
}
} 
else { 
// 
alert("You cannot use this button "); 
//window.parent.location.href=window.parent.location.href; 
}
```

Comment: There may be one too many closing brackets in `if(records.length && (window.confirm(Publish))))`

Answer (score 1):

Try writing you code like this. Let me know if it works.

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.ObjectName__c)};
var SelectedIds = '';
var first = true;
for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++){
 if(first){
  SelectedIds+="'"+records[i]+"'";
  first = false;
 }else
SelectedIds+=",'"+records[i]+"'";   
}
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id from ObjectName__c where Id in ("+SelectedIds+")");
```